# MariaDB: an implicit commit occurs on a partitioned table

Tags: mariadb

I have two tables: `main` and `secondary`. Both are InnoDB tables.

First of them is partitioned by range, there is currently only one partition in it.

```
| main | CREATE TABLE `main` (
  `main_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `the_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `partition_key` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` mediumblob,
  `completed_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `info` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `pk_main` (`main_id`),
  KEY `idx_main_types` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (partition_key)
(PARTITION main_201807 VALUES LESS THAN (201808) ENGINE = InnoDB) */ |
```

Secondary table is not partitioned.

```
| secondary | CREATE TABLE `secondary` (
  `sec_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `file_name_hash_md5` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `file_content_hash_md5` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sec_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq_secondary_file_name` (`file_name_hash_md5`,`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq_secondary_file_content` (`file_content_hash_md5`,`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

I'm running code that works inside a transaction. Transaction isolation is `READ_COMMITTED`, auto_commit is false. The code inserts one record to `main`, then one record to `secondary`, then commits if everything is ok.

But in my scenario the second `INSERT` fails due to UNIQUE constraint violation. In my code, I catch the corresponding exception before the transaction commits/rolls back and I mark the transaction for rollback. I can see in a debugger that `Connection#rollback()` actually gets called. I also enabled query log in MariaDB and I see just 3 queries in this connection (after it has been set up): two `INSERT`s and a `ROLLBACK`.

But after the rollback, the record that was inserted to `main` table remains there and does not get rolled back. Also, if I catch a breakpoint inside my code before a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` are issued (but after the two `INSERT`s were executed, one successful, another failed), I can see that `main` record from a different mysql client session, even though it should not yet be committed.

I know that some actions (like issuing a `TRUNCATE` in the same session) may cause an implicit commit, but I only have 2 `INSERT`s and one `ROLLBACK` in the log.

Why can this happen? And is there any tool that allows to trace such implicit commits (or the reason why the data was committed)?

MariaDB version is `10.0.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`

**Update**

In MariaDB with version 10.0.30-MariaDB-1~jessie it works correctly, so it seems that the problem is either that specific version (10.0.34) or Ubuntu-specific patches.

Comment: Unless you can reproduce this behaviour using the `mysql` CLI, I suspect there's something wrong with your application logic.

Comment: "the record that was inserted to main table remains there and does not get rolled back" -- what evidence do you have?  If you are in the same connection and not yet committed/rolledback, then this is probably correct.

Comment: @RickJames I'm just checking using `select * from main` from a different session in mysql client. I'm doing so both before the ROLLBACK is issued and after some time after it, and it both cases I can see the just-inserted `main` record.

Comment: In MariaDB with version `10.0.30-MariaDB-1~jessie` it works correctly, so it seems that the problem is either that specific version (`10.0.34`) or Ubuntu-specific patches.